# SQL MAX and LIMIT

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I want to write 5 people from the database with the highest earnings, in addition, employees must be currently employed.

I tried to do it but it does not go out.

```
SELECT 
    employees.first_name, employees.last_name, salaries.salary 
FROM 
    employees
INNER JOIN 
    salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
WHERE 
    (SELECT MAX(salaries.salary) 
     FROM salaries.salary
     WHERE salaries.to_date > '2018-07-10') 
LIMIT 5;
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Okey, sorry this is my first post

Comment: OK, no worries - but please **add that tag** now ....

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `subquery` :

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, s.salary
from employees e inner join
     salaries s
     on s.emp_no = e.emp_no
where s.to_date > '2018-07-10'  -- this seems incorrect to me needs to correct
order by s.salary desc
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
SELECT TOP 5
    employees.first_name, employees.last_name, salaries.salary 
FROM 
    employees
INNER JOIN 
    salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
ORDER BY
    salaries.salary DESC
```